# Ancestry visa tax and NI

Tags: united-kingdom, ancestry-visas

Good day

I would like to know if there is minimum requirement of hours one on an Ancestral visa or dependant on an an Ancestral visa needs to work. I.e if I only work 10 hours a week and earn £400 a month this is below the amount needed to pay for NI or Tax...is that ok? Do we have to pay tax as a visa requirement?
Also is being self employed as a dependant ok on the Visa ok?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum working hours or income requirement as such. Paragraph 186(iv) and (v) of the Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-5-working-in-the-uk say that an applicant must show he/she:

(iv) is able to work and intends to take or seek employment in the United Kingdom; and

(v) will be able to maintain and accommodate himself and any dependants adequately without recourse to public funds.

For the applicant to meet requirement (iv) UKVI must be satisfied that the applicant either:

• has a job in the UK

• genuinely intends to look for a job (or become self-employed) and is realistically able to do this
https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/576708/UK-Ancestry-v16.pdf

It is highly unlikely that an income of £400 per month would be deemed sufficient to meet the maintenance and accommodation requirement. For comparison, the median average UK wage is currently around £28,000 before taxes, and the cost of living can be high depending on the location, for example see https://www.expatica.com/uk/about/basics/cost-of-living-in-the-uk-1167475/

Tax https://www.gov.uk/income-tax/find-out-if-you-need-to-pay-income-tax and NI https://www.gov.uk/national-insurance are not covered within Immigration requirements. Both are payable above specific income levels.

Comment: @Sylvia Coetzee No need to thank me. If you think the answer addresses your question well, please ‘accept’ it by checking the grey ✔️ next to the answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers